# node script wait for async callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a simple js file I'm executing with `node script.js` that does some async stuff.

However, the script exits before the callbacks execute. I read that node "waits until callbacks are ran before exiting." This doesn't seem to be the case - what am I doing wrong?

```
// script.js
asyncOp(function(err, result) { 
  console.log('callback'); // <- this doesn't happen 
}
```

**Edit:** Here is a concrete example. This is the entire script

```
// script.js
var User = require('../models/user'); // a mongoose model

User.create({name: "bob"}, function(err, user) { 
  console.log('callback'); // <- this doesn't happen 
};
```

I execute it with `node script.js`, but it exits before "callback" gets printed

Comment: Can you make a simple case (full script) that mirrors what you're trying to do, how you're trying to do it, and fails? Your question is a bit open ended as it is.

Comment: @PatrickGunderson added a concrete example. This is the entire script.

Comment: looks like you need to connect to the server for the `create()` method to be executed http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html

Comment: It's not a node issue but user error (forgot to open a db connection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like you need to connect to the server for the create() method to be executed mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html